# asp.net paging, 1st page shows records, but 2nd page is empty

Tags: asp.net, gridview, page-index-changed

I've used asp.net gridview control. In gridview doing paging manually. But only first page shows the records. the page is completely blank. can anyone suggest what & where will I need to modify for the PageIndex Events?

Comment: Abracadabra! Hum... no. This did not make the code appear

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the page index of grid and bind it in [PageIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.pageindexchanged.aspx).

```
void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  YourFunctionToBindGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Solved 100% work

use this code inside 
Page_index_Changing
{
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Requseted_movie ORDER BY [ID] DESC", con);

SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DA1.Fill(DT1);

```
    GridView1.DataSource = DT1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: Don't post the same answer to more than one question. If the questions are basically the same, [flag them](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) as duplicates once you get enough rep. If they're different, customize the answer to the question's unique qualities.